# How to rename images uploaded in squarespace gallery

Tags: html, image, rename, file-rename, squarespace

I have a gallery / image slider on squarespace website. The images for the slider have been uploaded with random names like `186bgu342.jpg`, `8re67df.jpg`, etc.

I **want** to rename these images with **more meaningful names** for the sake of SEO.

I searched internet and found [this](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/27308/how-do-i-change-the-file-name-for-images-used-in-page-settings-thumbnail.html) and [this](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/76377/how-can-i-change-the-filenames-of-images-in-galleries.html). But none of them were helpful.

I also found [this link](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813928-Uploading-and-managing-files#toc-edit-a-file-name) , but I'm no able to open link editor for gallery images.

Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**To add/change alt tag for image blocks:**

1. Click on the Image Block.
2. Select "Caption Below"
3. Write a caption that you want as your alt text (below the image block, not in the settings editor)
4. Select "Do not display caption" – the caption text will disappear, but it will still populate your alt tag text!
5. Alternatively, you can type in the Filename(optional) box, which will change the name of your file and your alt text! (Both options are sufficient. I have not established if one option is better than the other, but I'm leaning toward filename because your keywords appear in url and alt, instead of just the alt as with the caption option.)
6. Here's a caption or filename example: "Blake's bio image" becomes alt="Blake's bio image" or alternatively, the filename is saved as "static1.squarespace.com/static/[long string]/blake%27s+bio+image?format=750w" and the alt text is alt="Blake's bio image".

**To change cover images:**

1. I would change the name of the file, which is uploaded.
2. So rename your saved image to include your keywords and upload. For example, the main homepage image could be named blake-awesome-personal-wesbite.jpeg.

Changing your file name changes the URL to have your keywords and changes the alt text :)

**To change gallery images:**

1. Click on the "edit" tab for the gallery section.
2. Click on the "gear" that shows above each image.
3. Click "Options" and you will see the file name, which you can edit
   (this will change your alt tag text and the URL text).

If you want even more details on how to do this, feel free to view this great resource from Squarespace support: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206542357